# Programmatically rewriting URL to a root application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, url-rewriting

I'm trying to route all controller actions from a child MVC application into the root MVC application.
My goal is to forward all request made to the "Account" controller in the Child application to the root application.

I tried using the Context.RewritePath but I get the Exception: "The virtual path maps to another application, which is not allowed."

```
Context.RewritePath("/Account/" + action);
```

The only way I could workaround this issue is by defining URL Rewrite rules in my web.config, but I don't like this approach because this has to be made and maintained in a lot of applications.

Does anyone know a way of rewriting to an URL in the root application?

P.S: I wouldn't mind using MVC routing if it would allow me to achieve this result.

BRGDS

Comment: I'm pretty sure the problem you are faced with is the fact that IIS will choose the application based on path.  So the root application will never have a chance to capture the request and redirect to itself.

Comment: Sure, but I'm trying to setup the Child application to redirect to the parent application.

Answer (score 0):

> Sure, but I'm trying to setup the Child application to redirect to the parent application.

I think the easiest way is to do something like (a bunch of assumptions here):

> http://www.myapplicationc.com/childapp/controller/action/1

```
public class RedirectController : Controller
{
  public ActionResult ToParentApplication()
  {
     var destination = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Replace("/childapp", string.Empty);
     return Redirect(destination);
  }
}
```

Then you can modular-ly add routes as needed:

```
routes.MapRoute(
  "Redirect1",
  "Account/{*pathInfo}",
  new { controller = "Redirect", action = "ToParentApplication" }
);
```

Or catch-all:

```
routes.MapRoute(
  "Catch All",
  "{*pathInfo}",
  new { controller = "Redirect", action = "ToParentApplication" }
);
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your suggestion. I tried your method, but unfortunately I need to issue an URL rewrite, not a redirect. Got any other ideas?

Comment: If you *have* to have a rewrite, you'll have to use IIS Url Rewriter.